# How can I convert .rb file to an entity relationship diagram?

Tags: ruby, database, entity-relationship

I would like to convert schema.rb file to an entity relationship diagram, in order to create a visual graph of my backend model.

Comment: Assuming this is rails (based on the information provided) the [`rails-erd`](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) gem does a decent job by leveraging the ORM relationships defined in the models

Comment: What he said ^^ --- but to emphasise, this uses information from the **models**  (e.g. `belongs_to :user`) and not the `schema.rb` file. In order to only use `schema.rb`, you really need to have set up correct foreign key constrains everywhere, which rails doesn't do by default (you need to explicitly define them in migrations).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `https://dbdiagram.io/` for free, and import your schema.rb file there.
It will create an ERD for you and let you export that in PDF, PNG, and few other formats.